# The Decimal Data Type in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2008, types, casting, decimal

Why does the following return `.500000` rather than `.500`?

```
SELECT 50 / CAST(100 AS decimal(3))
```

Comment: What's the difference? Seems like it's the **same and correct** value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are casting the divisor not the result. And you have not specified precision.

See this for examples:

```
SELECT 50 / CAST(100 AS decimal(3))
      ,50 / CAST(100 AS decimal(6,3))
      ,CAST (50 / CAST(100 AS decimal(3)) AS decimal(3))
      ,CAST (50 / CAST(100 AS decimal(3)) AS decimal(6,3))
```

[Precision, Scale, and Length (Transact-SQL)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190476.aspx)

> Precision is the number of digits in a number. Scale is the number of
>   digits to the right of the decimal point in a number. For example, the
>   number 123.45 has a precision of 5 and a scale of 2.

[DECIMAL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187746.aspx) uses a default precision of 18 and scale of 3.

Therefore when you case to DECIMAL(3) you get a DECIMAL(3,0). Then you use it as a divisor and SQL Server follows its rules for the resultant scale.

```
Operation  Result precision                     Result scale
e1 / e2    p1 - s1 + s2 + max(6, s1 + p2 + 1)   max(6, s1 + p2 + 1)
```

Comment: Thanks, Karl. I got that part on casting the divisor. But why the query result is .500000, not .5, .500, the default 18 digits, or others?

Comment: Great! Thanks. Explains very well.